# Have content text flow under sidebar div on large screens - Foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

SOLVED - here's the link to the Foundation forums where it was answered: 
http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/3294-have-content-text-flow-under-sidebar-div-on-large-screens#

ORIGINAL QUESTION -

I have a two column layout with the left being a few paragraphs and the right being a sidebar div with links. I would like:

On large screens: The text to flow to full-width underneath the sidebar. (Like if it was a float based layout.) Currently, the columns restrict this so that the paragraphs stay in their defined columns.

On medium and small screens: The paragraphs to take full-width AND appear at the top. The sidebar coming only after they are complete.

Also, I'd prefer it if it didn't require any additional javascript but instead was just basic HTML, CSS and Foundation....

Here's a codepen with it looking as it should on large screens but behaving badly everywhere else. http://cdpn.io/LIKfa

Any insight is much appreciated!